# How to change the color of the Option name inside the select tag?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically constructing html and appending it to the HTML  select tag

This is my code

```
var companies = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","OTHERS","TEN"];

var comapnieshtml = '<option value="" selected>All Companies</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
                    comapnieshtml += '<option value="' + companies[i] + '">' + companies[i] + '</option>'
                }
                $("#companieslist").html(comapnieshtml);
```

My requirement is that if the option value is Others i want to display it in a separate color

This is my fiddle

Could you please let me know how to achive this

http://jsfiddle.net/jm9zp0pp/3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Answer (score -1):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o9suqu0y/1/

```
$(function(){
    $("#companieslist").change(function(){
        if ($('#companieslist').val() == "OTHERS"){
            $("#companieslist").css('color','red')
        }
        else{
            $("#companieslist").css('color','black')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you , but i couldn't see green color in your fiddle for the others know

Comment: my requirement is that Others should be displayed in green color itself

Comment: @PreethiJain The code is working properly with green colored background, when Others is selected. If you want the fore color to be green, then you can simply edit the given code.

Answer (score -1):

You can add css using jquery. Check if the option is selected using jquery, if not u can add css attribute.

**CSS**

```
.color{
color:#0F0F0F;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
    $('#mySelectBox option').each(function() {

        if(!$(this).is(':selected')){
            $(this).addClass(color);
        }
    }
```

This way you can add the class only to the elements which are not selected

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
var companies = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","OTHERS","TEN"];

var comapnieshtml = '<option value="" selected>All Companies</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {

                if (companies[i]=="OTHERS")
                {comapnieshtml += '<option style="color:green" value="' + companies[i] + '">' + companies[i] + '</option>'}
                else
                {comapnieshtml += '<option style="color:black" value="' + companies[i] + '">' + companies[i] + '</option>'}
            }
            $("#companieslist").html(comapnieshtml);

$(function(){
$("#companieslist").change(function(){
    if ($('#companieslist').val() == "OTHERS"){
        $("#companieslist").css('color','green')
    }
    else{
        $("#companieslist").css('color','black')
    }
})
})
```

Simply edited the answer given by @Rajan. Credit goes to him.